# How to execute multiple functions angular at the same time when a checkbox is ticked

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a checkbox, that when checked / unchecked runs a function:

```
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="display: block">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="parentCheckbox" name="parentCheckbox"
                 [ngModel]="hasAcceptedCheckbox"  (ngModelChange)="oncheckboxAcceptanceChange($event)">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
          <span class="custom-control-description">
            <span id="cookiePolicyLabelStart">
              ....
          </span>
        </label>

  get hasAcceptedCheckbox(): boolean {
    return this.hasAcceptedchild1 && this.hasAcceptedchild2 && this.hasAcceptedchild3 
  }


  oncheckboxAcceptanceChange(event) {

      this.Onchild1Acceptance(event);

      this.Onchild2Acceptance(event); 

      this.Onchild3Acceptance(event);
   }
```

an example of one of the 3 methods I am trying to run

```
      Onchild1Acceptance(newValue: boolean): void {
            .....
  }
```

so when i run the above, the oncheckboxAcceptanceChange method only fires each method one at a time per click, Im trying to make them all fire at the same time and I'm having trouble with making it all happen at once.

any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that it only fires one per click? Seeing your code it should call the three of them.

Comment: because each child checkbox unchecks one at a time in the front end, rather than all at once. I can't pinpoint why. when you hit  parentCheckbox child1 unticks only, hit parentCheckbox again and then child2 unticks etc. its a rather bizarre bug.

Comment: Please describe your goal. What is your app supposed to do here? Do I get you right, that you want to to uncheck several checkboxes by clicking one?

Comment: thats right! if parent checkbox is clicked, the all child checkboxes should be unchcked, if parent is checked, child boxes should be checked

Comment: Please, show the entire HTML-code and TS-code.